# Como puedo ver los mensajes de alert en PHP antes de que me redireccione a otra página

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

quiero mostrar lo ocurrido al guardar una imagen en la base de datos y después redireccionar a otra página con un header, y no puedo ver los mensajes de alert indicando si se guardó la imagen. Este es mi código:

```
<?php
    require 'conexion.php';
    $escuela=5;
    $cvealumno=13;  
    $archivotemp=$_FILES["archivo"]["name"];
    $ruta = 'files/'.$escuela.'/'.$cvealumno.'/';
    $tiempo=time();
    $archivo=$ruta.$tiempo.$archivotemp;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO personasfoto (escuela, cvealumno, fotocarpeta) VALUES ('$escuela', '$cvealumno', '$archivo')";

    mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    if($_FILES["archivo"]["error"]>0){
        echo "Error al cargar archivo"; 
        } else {    
        $permitidos = array("image/gif","image/png","image/jpg","image/jpeg","image/bmp" );
        $limite_kb = 400;

        if(in_array($_FILES["archivo"]["type"], $permitidos) && $_FILES["archivo"]["size"] <= $limite_kb * 1024){

            if(!file_exists($ruta)){
                mkdir($ruta, 0777,true);
            }
            if(!file_exists($archivo)){

                $resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"], $archivo);

                if($resultado){
                    //echo "Archivo Guardado";
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Archivo Guardado");</script>'; 
                    } else {
                    //echo "Error al guardar archivo";
                    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Error al guardar archivo");</script>';   
                }

                } else {
                //echo "Archivo ya existe";
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Archivo ya existe");</script>';  
            }

            } else {
            //echo "Archivo no permitido o excede el tamaño";
            echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Archivo no permitido o excede el tamaño");</script>';    
        }

    }
 header("location:indexfoto.php");

?>
```

-
Gracias de antemano, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Espero te sirva:

```
  $mensaje = 'Archivo no permitido o excede el tamaño'; // se guarda en mensaje el texto que quieras mostrar
  header("Location: indexfoto.php?Message=" . urlencode($mensaje));
```

y en tu archivo indexfoto.php

```
    if (isset($_GET['Message'])) {
    echo $_GET['Message'];
     }
```

Si necesitas usar un modal

```
if (isset($_GET['Message'])) {
print '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $_GET['Message'] . '");</script>';

         }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703854/php-give-alert-popup-then-redirect-the-page

Comment: Muchas gracias, probaré el código, saludos.